# How to set "destoryOnHide" or "destroyOnClose" to modal dialog which is existing, in Liferay?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, liferay, liferay-aui

I have modal dialog in Liferay 6.2
Is there any way to set destoryOnHide or destroyOnClose to dialog, but after render process?

Answer (score 3):

If you have a reference to the Dialog object, you can use the set Operation. For example:

```
var dlg = Liferay.Util.Window.getWindow({ id: 'd123', ..your-config-obj.. });
// now it is rendered
dlg.set('destroyOnHide', false);
```

Unfortunatelly, i did not see a similar thing for destroyOnClose, but you can try to do this in same way.
If you dont have a reference to the dialog, you can get one with (for Example)

```
Liferay.Util.Window.getById('d123');
```

Also make sure you have a dependency to 'liferay-util-window' in your script.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for answer. This code works in my case:

```
var modal = Liferay.Util.getWindow('windowID');
modal._state.data.destroyOnHide.lazy.value = true;
```